# Python format terminal data with realtime updating

Tags: python, shell, command-line, terminal, ascii

I worded the title the best I possibly could. I'll further explain.

I understand how to make boxes such as

```
----------------
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

I basically want the data inside the box to update in realtime. So if I wanted a number to increment from 1 through 10 it would refresh and update the number. 1 then replaced by a 2, then 3, so on and so forth.

Is there any python libraries for this or are there built in functions?

Hopefully the question I'm asking makes sense, I wasn't sure how to word it for an effective Google search. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `curses` https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 0):

The curses package should be able to do pretty much everything you want:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html